# CASE WHEN does not exist on Access SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, ms-access-2013

I discovered a couple of hours ago that `CASE WHEN` doesn't work on access queries. I have a complex CONCAT on my SELECT statement but it is written in MySQL:

```
SELECT CONCAT(
'www.mywebsite.com/catalogsearchtool?title='
, REPLACE(tblTitles.Content_Name, '&', '%26')
, '&contributor=ln:'
, CASE WHEN LOCATE('; ',tblTitles.Contributors) > 0
THEN REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(
CASE WHEN RIGHT(TRIM(tblTitles.Contributors), 1) = ',' THEN LEFT(TRIM(tblTitles.Contributors), CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(tblTitles.Contributors)) - 1) ELSE TRIM(tblTitles.Contributors) END
, '&', '%26'), '; ', ',rl:Author&contributor=ln:'), ', ', ',fn:')

ELSE REPLACE(REPLACE(
CASE WHEN RIGHT(TRIM(tblTitles.Contributors), 1) = ',' THEN LEFT(TRIM(tblTitles.Contributors), CHAR_LENGTH(TRIM(tblTitles.Contributors)) - 1) ELSE TRIM(tblTitles.Contributors) END
, '&', '%26'), ', ', ',fn:')
END
, ',rl:Author&language='
, LOWER(tblTitles.language)
) AS 'link'
```

Basically what that does is that it generates a link based on names that can be found in a column called Contributors. That column has the following order:

```
last_name, first_name
```

or

```
last_name, first_name; last_name, first_name
```

For reasons out of my control, there can be many names in that column. So for the query above a couple of results would be (for 2 names):

```
www.mywebsite.com/catalogsearchtool?title=tile123&contributor=ln:smith,fn:john,rl:Author&contributor=ln:smith,fn:jane,rl:Author&language=english
```

And (for 1 name):

```
www.mywebsite.com/catalogsearchtool?title=title5678&contributor=ln:smith,fn:john,rl:Author&language=english
```

Can anyone please help me translating this logic to Access SQL?

Comment: You're looking for IIF(): http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/iif.php

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29681652/2589202) can offer some insight.